# A formula in Excel to count the number of rows where there is a date in column 'K' but column 'N' is blank?

Tags: excel

I am a little rusty to say the least and in Excel I would like to create a formula that counts the number of cases that have been closed without a certain stage taking place.

So, the formula would need to count the number of rows where there is a date in column k, but no date in `column n` (the cell is blank). Any help would be appreciated. I have had a go with `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`=COUNTIFS(K:K,">0",N:N,"")`

that's counting rows where K is greater than zero but N is blank [""]

Comment: Thank you, Barry, that's great and has done the trick. So much neater than the one I came up with too. You're a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use another column try this formula, for every row of the column:

```
=IF(K1>0,1,0)*IF(N1="";1;0)
```

then you have to sum column values.

Instead of `K1>0` you can use two cell for date so you can count cells within a range of date.

Answer (score 0):

For a start try something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((K1:K100<>"")*(N1:N100=""))
```

Comment: Thanks, Gary, appreciate your help.